# Need help understanding why javascript object property is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help understanding why the following piece of code returns an undefined object property:

```
var count = 0;
var intervals = {
    collection : []                      
}

intervals.collection[0] = function () {
    this.timer = setInterval(function(){
       count++;
       $("p").html(count);            
    }, 1000);
}();

if(typeof intervals.collection[0] === "undefined") {
    $("span").html("undefined");        
}​
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tvaQk/8/

Basically, I'd like to be able to keep a collection of setIntervals that I can reference later so I can loop through and clear. I was thinking I'd be able to loop through the intervals.collection array and do something like:

`clearInterval(intervals.collection[0].timer)`

but cannot since `intervals.collection[0]` is undefined

Comment: you need to `return this;` inside the self-invoking function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `return`.

```
intervals.collection[0] = function () {
  return this.timer = setInterval(function(){
--^^^^^^--
```

Notice `this` refers to `window`, I'm not sure if adding a property `timer` to the `window` element is what you were expecting actually. Otherwise, you shall return the interval id to not clutter the global `window` scope.

---

A short way to being able to access the `timer` using `intervals.collection[0].timer` is by creating an Object instead:

```
intervals.collection.push({
  timer: setInterval(function(){
    count++;
    $("p").html(count);            
  }, 1000)
});

console.log(intervals.collection[0].timer);
```

I used `Array.push` in this example to add the newly created interval as the last element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're complicating things... What I would do is just push the interval straight into the array.

```
intervals.collection.push( setInterval(function(){...}, 1000) );
```

You don't need an IIFE to execute the interval, when you push it into the array it'll execute as well.

Then you can clear them all like:

```
intervals.collection.forEach(function( timer ) {
  clearInterval( timer );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply write it like this:

```
intervals.collection[0] = setInterval(function(){
    $("p").html(++count);            
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this answer. You are returning the `window` and not a newly created object as I explained in my answer

Comment: @Alexander Sometimes I wonder whether people actually look at posts before upvoting them...

Comment: @phant0m, Well, unexperienced people believes in anything anyone posts

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a self-invoking function, which means you assign the return value of the function. The function itself doesn't return anything therefore it's undefined.